# How to get more tomatoes in single tree?

Tags: tomatoes

I am from India.    I  have few tomato trees `since two years`. but I didn't get more tomatoes in that tree. actually I am getting maximum `8-10 tomatoes.`

I found some `best tomato tree` in website. it may give more than `40-60 tomatoes`.

**Here is a image of that tree.**

[image]

**Here is another one:**

[image]

my question is, how to **get more tomatoes from single tree** like above image.?

Comment: Assuming you haven't made the pictures yourself, please think about putting the reference of the images inside your question or any other legal statement which shows that we can show the photos here without getting problems in the future. Otherwise, it is my understanding and I'm afraid your question will be removed. I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: I  think we can use images here to describe our questions  in simple way.so, anyone can easily understand our question and I took some reference images to describe  question for clear understanding.

Comment: @Dineshcool giving credit for the photos (especially because they aren't hosted in their original location) is just good netiquette.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are some fantastic images!  Proof that growing tomatoes can be an art in more ways than one.

Some tomatoes are hybrids.  Hybrids take the fruit characteristics of one plant and combine it with the high-yield characteristics of another.  Then when grown in a greenhouse where conditions are absolutely controlled, images like those can be presented.

This man, http://www.youtube.com/user/mhpgardener/videos has produced some impressive videos of tomatoes and seems to enjoy showing everyone how to do it.  Scrolling through his list of videos will show tomatoes almost as nice as the ones you posted.  He also responds to all comments to his videos, should you have a question for him.

**How to get MORE tomatoes (not bigger tomatoes) from a single tree:**

**Cultivar Selection**

Cultivar selection will affect the number of tomatoes more than anything.  Some varieties yield many fruits (the cherry tomatoes can produce 100s per plant per season, but the fruit are small) and other varieties produce large fruit, but few of them.

**Tomato Cultivar Trial and Pruning Observation**

You will get more yield (total season fruit weight) if you don't prune.  You might get bigger fruit (but less of them) if you do prune.  By pruning, you're effectively thinning the fruit.

> The most striking difference at harvest was larger
>   fruit size (.69 lb vs. .55 lb) from pruned plots. However, pruning also reduced the number of fruit harvested
>   by 32% and total marketable weight by 15%.

http://www.public.iastate.edu/~taber/Extension/Progress%20Rpt%2000/tomato.pdf

Its possible to get bigger fruit by pruning, but its not guaranteed.  I've read studies saying there was no significant difference between fruit size of pruned and unpruned plants.  Though there is always a significant difference in total yield.

> Removing side shoots may reduce overall tomato harvest. In fact, in a study by Purdue University, and published in Organic Gardening Magazine, scientists found that removing side shoots was shown to increase the average fruit weight some of the time but did not increase the total harvest for each individual plant.

http://www.grow-tomato-sauce.com/pruning.html

So with selection of the proper variety, having good conditions for growth of tomatoes, and not pruning too much, you can have large yields from a single tomato tree.

Comment: Excellent Explanation with nice video demo.

Comment: is there any difference between hybrid and normal seeds  in cost? and we need to fellow separate framing process to cultivate hybrid  seeds?

Comment: @Dineshcool Hybrid seeds cost more because there is a lot of work that goes into producing them. Also, you can't save the seeds from hybrids and replant them... well, you can, but they won't have the same characteristics of the hybrid. So, each year, you have to buy more hybrid seed. Hybrid plants usually grow better and have more resistance to disease, so no special farming practices.

Comment: @Dineshcool Another thing to consider is hybrids are bred to be disease resistant and to have fruit that is marketable, meaning they're round and pretty. Heirlooms are usually an ugly fruit. Heirlooms take longer to reach maturity. But I feel heirlooms taste better and are more nutritious. Much of the nutrition of food has been bred-out in hybrids, in favor of appearance.

Comment: you made me to understand about this topic more clear. Have a great day. I got it.